# stdlib not found when configuring Python interpreter in PyDef

Tags: python

I try to Configure the Interpreter in PyDef. I downloaded Python3.6.1 from [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-361/).

When i Configure the Interpreter, i go to `PyDef->Interpreters->Python Interpreter`, click on new, fill "Interpreter Name:" with "Python" , 
Browse my Interpreter Executable `(C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\python36\python.exe)`, click OK twice and it says Python stdlib not found or stdlib found without .py files.

I did download python from the link above again and i don't see any lib folder, only `lib2to3`, and no .py files at all. What am i doing wrong? Why are these files not at the download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using the installer instead of downloading the zip. Dont know why the lib is not contained in the zip though.